# Understanding why this buffer overflow attack isn't working

Tags: buffer-overflow, python, c

I'm doing a buffer overflow challenge, and I can't understand what exactly I'm doing wrong. Through debugging, I managed to figure out how my input should look like such that I can force the program to return to a function. From gdb I figured if I entered "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa**cdef**bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb" I can get the program to return to cdef of 0x66656463. Here's a sc just in case:
[image]
As you can see, the program managed to go to 0x66656463. Now I the function's address through gdb and I tried placing this in cdef's spot in little endian order using pwntools:

```
payload = "a" * 28 + "\x56\x85\x04\x08" + "b"*47
msg = "-1\n" + payload

io.sendline(msg)
```

The reason for the "-1\n" is because the program asks for input twice: the first time I just enter -1 and then the second input I try the exploit. So far, I'm just getting a segfault and the address I want to jump to should be starting a shell for me to exploit. I'm not sure what exactly I'm doing wrong, and any help would be appreciated. If I had to guess it's that I'm somehow dealing with the two inputs incorrectly (they're being read via fgets() in C if that matters.)

EDIT: I have the source binary and I tried running it locally. I created the following txt file

```
-1
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaV\x85\x04\x08bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
```

and I redirect it in gdb via

```
run < <(cat input.txt)
```

this works the same but whenever I add an escaped hex in place of the cdef, I get a different seg fault at a different address:
[image]

It looks like if I replace any of the cdef with an escaped hex, I get a segfault at 0x08048726. Is something wrong with passing in the bytes?

Comment: Which function is stored in 0x66656463 address ? you get segfault because your program tries to access an address(0x66656463) not authorized.

Answer (score 1):

CDEF in hexadecimal characters is 66656463 (little endianness), but this address doesn't point to any function and not permitted to access. So the program crashs. You have to modify your shellcode with a valid address who points to a function like execve syscall, with /bin/sh (for example) as parameter of the function.

Comment: Yes, I know that 0x66656463 corresponds to cdef; I showed that to prove that I found what input to modify to change the return address. Like I said in my post, I then changed the cdef to correspond to another function that spawns a shell but this isn't working as expected.